# Using a component-wise approach (using partial derivatives), show that the gradient of $f$ is given by $\nabla f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(A +A^T)x + b$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

Using a component-wise approach (using partial derivatives), show that the gradient  of $f$ is given by te following formulas

\begin{align*}
\nabla f(x) &= \frac{1}{2}(A +A^T)x + b\\
\end{align*}

For $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$
We note $A = (a_{ij})_{\substack{
 1\leq i\leq n \\
 1\leq j\leq n}}$, $b = (b_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$, $x = (x_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$

Then 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_i a_{ij}x_j + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i x_i$$

$$
\nabla f(x) = \big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)\big)_{1\leq i \leq n}
$$

\begin{align*}
\forall k\leq n: \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x) &=\frac{1}{2} = \big[\sum_{i\neq k}x_i a_{ik} + \sum_{j\neq k}a_{kj}x_j + 2a_{kk}x_k\big] + b_k \quad (1)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ia_{ik} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{kj}x_j\big] + b_k \quad (2)\\
x_i 
&=\frac{1}{2} \big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ik} x_i+ \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{kj}x_j\big] + b_k \\ 
&=\frac{1}{2}\big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ik} + a_{kj} x_i\big] + b_k \\
 \nabla f(x) &= \frac{1}{2}(A +A^T)x + b\
\end{align*}

Here are my questions
- what does exactly the $k$ represent in (1) and why can't it be equal to $i$?
- how can we go from (1) to (2) and from $\sum_{i\neq k}$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing the partial derivative with respect to the component $x_k$; this is the $k$ throughout the computation.

There is some casework to do when computing the partial derivative of each addend.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (a_{ij} x_i x_j) = \begin{cases}2 a_{kk} x_k^2 & i=j=k \\ a_{kj} x_j & i=k, j \ne k \\ a_{ik} x_i & i \ne k, j = k \\ 0 & i \ne k, j \ne k\end{cases}$$

Doing this term by term in the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j$ yields (1).

To get (2), just combine sums:
$$\sum_{i \ne k} a_{ik} x_i + a_{kk} x_k = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik} x_i$$
$$\sum_{j \ne k} a_{kj} x_j + a_{kk} x_k = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} x_i$$

---

Response to comment:

It's not as complicated as you think. Just ask yourself how to compute the following:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (a_{kk} x_k x_k)\\
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (a_{kj} x_k x_j) & j \ne k\\
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (a_{ik} x_i x_k) & i \ne k\\
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (a_{ij} x_i x_j) & i \ne k, j \ne k
\end{align}

Finally, $\sum_{j \ne k}$ is a sum over all possible values of $j$ in $1, \ldots, n$ excluding $k$. So if $n=5$ and $k=2$, the sum is over $j$ in $\{1,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @angryavian for your answer. Where can I find the proof of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (a_{ij} x_i x_j) = \begin{cases}2 a_{kk} x_k^2 & i=j=k \\ a_{kj} x_j & i=k, j \ne k \\ a_{ik} x_i & i \ne k, j = k \\ 0 & i \ne k, j \ne k\end{cases}$ and how should I put in word $\sum_{j\ne k}$: "the sum of... starting to $j$ but $j$ not equal to $k$"?

Comment: @ecjb See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The index $k$ stands for any index in the range $1, \cdots, n$. It does not make sense to make it equal to $i$ because $i$ is also a dummy sum variable in the formula. If you really want to use $i$, just write $f$ equivalently as

$$
f(x)=\frac 12 \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} x_k x_j +  \sum_{k=1}^n b_k x_k
$$

and proceed from there computing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$.